# sql csv export shows incorrect sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, csv

I am runnning query on sql server 2012 and exporting cost records in csv by save  result as option, sum of all records in csv shows 1817751.612

```
SELECT SUM(Cost) AS COST FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY ...,...,...;

COST 
0.005719641
0
3.56
0.167338156
0.007596698
1.78
0.03634226
......
.....
...
```

However the results while checking SUM for all cost records is 1823065.094

```
SELECT SUM(Z.COST) FROM(SELECT SUM(Cost) AS COST FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY ...,...,...) AS Z;
```

Why does the csv shows sum as 1817751.612 instead of 1823065.094 and how can I correct it ?
I have tried using CAST, ROUND and CONVERT as well for Sum column, did not work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you summing twice?

Comment: The first query gives me records which I export to csv, the second query tells me the sum of those records. Problem is they should be same in csv and in DB but I see the difference which is why I posted the query I am using

Answer (score 1):

Try running the counts using decimals:

```
SELECT SUM(Z.COST)
FROM (SELECT SUM(CAST(Cost as DECIMAL(38, 20)) AS COST
      FROM TABLE_NAME
      GROUP BY ...,...,...
     ) AS Z;
```

In all likelihood, the problem is due to the large number of numbers that you have and the fact that you are using floats.  I am speculating that the type is really a 4-byte float rather than an 8-byte.  If so, this could be due to rounding errors.

Comment: Query shows sum of all cost records as 1823065.09429799316082651000 and when I used SELECT SUM(CAST(Cost as DECIMAL(38, 20)) AS COST FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY ...,...,...; and saved all records in csv file it shows sum as 1823065.094 :) Thank you Gordon...also it does not show any exponents since it is getting all numbers with 20 decimal places

Comment: @SanjaySingh . . . This would appear to be the correct sum.  I would suggest that you change the data type of the column -- just to be safe.  The problem would apparently be the use of 4-byte floats when validating the CSV file.  So, it is your validation code, not the database.

Comment: Ran into another issue while extracting more grouped records in csv

Comment: Extracting more data now, using query SELECT SUM(CAST(Cost as DECIMAL(38, 20)) AS COST,Center,Location,StartDATE,ENdDATE  FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY Center,Location,StartDATE,ENdDATE; and after exporting cost records to csv it shows sum to be 1817751.612 which is the original issue, I have checked sum using SELECT SUM(Z.COST) FROM(SELECT SUM(CAST(Cost as DECIMAL(38, 20)) AS COST,Center,Location,StartDATE,ENdDATE  FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY Center,Location,StartDATE,ENdDATE) AS Z; and it still shows sum should be 1823065.09429799316082651000 ...... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @SanjaySingh . . . Questions should be asked as questions, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us which type do you use for column `Cost`?

This can be due to the implicit conversion between sql type and csv type

I don't have opportunity to add comment, sorry.

Comment: Hi Liden, no issues for not adding comment, just happy that you could help. I have checked and found the data type is float